# Deleting log files from all user profiles during uninstallation in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, inno-setup, uninstallation

My app writes log files in application data folder of every local account. I'd like to delete them all during uninstallation. Seems I can't just add a `UninstallDelete` section like this:

```
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{sd}\Users\\*\AppData\Roaming\MyLogFolder"
```

Or can I iterate over all user accounts and delete my log folders one by one. I just have no idea how to do it in Inno Setup script. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely cannot use wildcards in directory components of a path.

You have to write a code to delete the logs from individual profiles, one by one. For an example code, see:
[Inno Setup Create individual shortcuts on all desktops of all users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35224772/850848)